# regular expression to separate title, first name, last name throughout the list and store data in a new list

Tags: python, regex, list

I have got a list like below which I have read from a CSV usng Python

```
list_FN = [[' Braund', ' Mr. Owen Harris ', '1'], [' Heikkinen', ' Miss. Laina ', '0'], [' Allen', ' Mr. William Henry ', '0'],....]
```

I want to use regular expression to separate title, first name, last name throughout the list and store data in a new list.

I am new to regular expressions and having trouble finding a soution.

So far what I have done is

```
    with open('/home/username/Desktop/FairDealCustomerData.csv', newline='') as f:
      reader = csv.reader(f)
      data1 = list(reader)
      print(data1)

l1 = data1[0]
print(l1)
```

Ouput:

```
[[' Braund', ' Mr. Owen Harris ', '1'], [' Heikkinen', ' Miss. Laina ', '0'], [' Allen', ' Mr. William Henry ', '0'], [' Moran', ' Mr. James ', '0']...


[' Braund', ' Mr. Owen Harris ', '1']
```

Comment: What is the expected output you want assuming you already have `list_FN`?

Comment: We need more details - are the titles always composed of a single word that ends with a period?  On your examples, what exactly do you consider to be a part of the first name and last name?

Comment: Identifying first and last names in arbitrary text is [a hard problem](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: It looks like your CSV has spaces after the commas, they should be removed.